# Windows 7 XP Mode USB Scanner

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb, scanner, windows-xp-mode

I have a Windows 7 machine with a legacy scanning program. I have my virtual XP machine setup and working with the software, but I'm having issues getting XP mode to see the Fujitsu fi-4120, Windows 7 sees it just fine. When I try to attach it to XP mode under USB, it shows Unidentified Device. I have Integrated features turned on.

I've installed the Fujitsu driver software package in XP mode, which installs the driver, but it still shows up. I've redownloaded the software too. I try to manually install it, including using Leg Room to try and see if I can find an INF file to install the driver to no avail.

I know I'm missing something. Can anyone assist?

Comment: I opened XP mode on my PC, I have a canon scanner installed and turned on in W7, I used the USB attach function, it recognized my canon though the driver was not installed yet, I did notice when I hit the canon to attach it, W7 got a popup about a Virtual stub installer, then XP mode popped up the new hardware wizard to look for a driver. Do you have the driver for the fujitsu installed in W7, for W7 to pass the hardware to XP mode it needs to know what it is first.

Comment: I don't want to assume anything. By USB attach function, you mean the USB drop down at the top. That lists "unknown device" in my XP mode. However the device does show up in the device manager in W7. I'm going to go back over this and check for the Virtual stub installer, I don't recall seeing that. The new hardware wizard did show up in XP though, just couldn't get it to recignize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like this was caused directly from a real bad driver installation method.

I started from the top down. I redownloaded this a third time, this first installation .exe file is just an extractor (which doesn't work with either 7 Zip, or leg room). After that you install another setup file, which installs software, then reboots your computer, after that it installs more twain drivers. Now after that reboot you can go to attach the device and it picks up the device fine.

Thanks for your time